# Knapsack-problem with files on DVDs

Tags: windows, windows-7, cloud-storage, optical-media

I have n video files, while each file has the size s_n. I have DVDs with a max size of 4.7 GB. Which program - or algorithm that I can simply implement in c# - gives me playlists for each DVD that I can use to copy the files to the DVDs, using the space as good as possible?

I know, it is a knapsack problem.

```
OS: Windows 7
Price: free
```

Comment: Knapsack should not be an issue for small `n`. What is `n` roughly in your case?

Comment: @Thomas: ninety.